# Realm file upload, can't able to process the data inside it, ( no realm export and import ) in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, mongodb, react-native, realm

There is no official way to export or import the realm data. I am able to download the .realm file but can't able to retrieve the data from that.

this is the export function

```
import Realm from 'realm';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import {getRealm} from './realmService';

export const exportRealmData = async () => {
  try {
    const realm: Realm = await getRealm();
    const exportFileName = 'qqqq.realm';
    const exportFilePath = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${exportFileName}`;

    if (await RNFS.exists(exportFilePath)) {
      await RNFS.unlink(exportFilePath);
    }

    const config = {
      path: exportFilePath,
      schema: realm.schema,
      schemaVersion: realm.schemaVersion + 1,
      encryptionKey: realm.encryptionKey,
    };

    realm.writeCopyTo(config);

    const downloadsFolder = RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath;
    const destinationFilePath = `${downloadsFolder}/${exportFileName}`;

    await RNFS.moveFile(exportFilePath, destinationFilePath);

    console.log('Realm data exported to', destinationFilePath);
    return destinationFilePath;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error exporting Realm data', error);
  }
};
```

I have tried to upload and retrieve the data, but i am unable to do that

```
  function normalizePath(path: string | undefined) {
    try {
      if (path === undefined) {
        throw console.error('undefined');
      }
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios' || Platform.OS === 'android') {
        const filePrefix = 'file:';
        if (path.startsWith(filePrefix)) {
          path = path.substring(filePrefix.length);
        }
        path = decodeURIComponent(path);
        return path;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error({msg: 'Failed to normalize path', data: e});
    }
  }

  const handleFilePick = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await DocumentPicker.pick({
        type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
      });
      console.log(result);
      const {0: file1} = result;

      const path = normalizePath(file1?.uri);
      console.log(path);
      setRealmFile(path);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  console.log(realmFile);

  const handleDataSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      if (!realmFile) {
        console.error('Please upload a .realm file');
        return;
      }

      const realm = await getRealm();
      const existingRealm = await Realm.open({path: realmFile.uri});

      console.log('This is the existing realm:', existingRealm);

      realm.write(() => {
        [User, Category, Expense, Currency, Debtor, Debt].forEach(schema => {
          const objects = existingRealm.objects(schema.schema.name);
          console.log(`Data for ${schema.schema.name}:`, objects.toJSON());

          objects.forEach(object => {
            realm.create(schema.schema.name, object, Realm.UpdateMode.Modified);
          });
        });
      });

      await AsyncStorageService.setItem('isOnboarded', JSON.stringify(true));
      dispatch(setIsOnboarded(true));

      console.log('Data updated successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating data:', error);
    }
  };
```

This is the log

```
 LOG  content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:1000000035
 LOG  [{"fileCopyUri": null, "name": "qqqq.realm", "size": 4848, "type": "application/octet-stream", "uri": "content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf%3A1000000035"}]
 LOG  content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:1000000035
 LOG  This is the existing realm: {"beforeNotifyListeners": {"eventType": "beforenotify", "listeners": Set {}, "realm": [Circular]}, "changeListeners": {"eventType": "change", "listeners": Set {}, "realm": [Circular]}, "schemaExtras": {}, "schemaListeners": {"eventType": "schema", "listeners": Set {}, "realm": [Circular]}, "syncSession": null}
```

help me retrieving the data from .realm file in react native

Answer (score 0):

*There is no official way to export or import the realm data*

[Realm Studio](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases) can both import as well as export data.

You can also use the mongoexport command line tool as well. The command dumps your collection to a flat file containing JSON data.

The mongoexport command is documented [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/?tck=docs_chatbot&_ga=2.234276060.338828397.1703182124-1433341686.1692637657)

There's also a video in the MongoDB University covering [Export](https://learn.mongodb.com/learn/course/mongodb-database-administrator-tools/lesson-4-data-export-tools/learn?tck=docs_chatbot&_ga=2.192268136.338828397.1703182124-1433341686.1692637657) from an Admin perspective.

A third option is to write up some quick code using one the SDK's to dump the data to a file - should be about 15 lines of code.

Also - if you log into the MongoDB Console and go to Data Services at the top, then the tab for collections is probably selected. Select Cmd Line Tools tab, then about 1/2 way down there's a whole section for Data Import and Export Tools

[image]